# Query returned non-zero code: 10, cause: FAILED

Tags: hive

all
when I use the Hive to select the id from a table there are some errors occurring as follows:

Query returned non-zero code: 10, cause: FAILED : Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:68 Invalid table alias or column reference 'Goldman'

can any body give me some questions?

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to indicate that you are doing a select for a column named Goldman that does not exist. You attempting to do an HQL query for a column goldman or you are attempting to do a query for rows in which a specific column has Goldman.

Comment: Line 1:68 Invalid table alias or column reference 'Goldman': (possible column names are: id, company, equity, table_flag, update_time): SELECT mock_equity.id FROM mock_equity WHERE (mock_equity.company = Goldman AND mock_equity.company IS NOT NULL AND mock_equity.id IS NOT NULL)                                                       I feel very surprised. I can find the company column contains the value 'Goldman' in table. but it doesn't work.